# R Notebook with dlookr package

Tags: r, rnotebook

I try to create Data summary with `dlookr` package. In normal `R` it works but in `R notebook` it has a notification like this:

> Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 251

Anybody knows why?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandoc is a program that R Studio relies on to create html files. You may be required to download (https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/releases/tag/2.4) and install (instructions here: https://pandoc.org/installing.html) the pandoc program on your computer. I would also recommend downloading and install MiKTeX (mentioned on the pandoc install page mentioned above; see here: https://miktex.org/) which will allow you to create pdf files.